# Zoo Visitor update_form to update only some entries wipes out all other data

Tags: zoo-visitor

I've got a Zoo Visitor update_form which i want to use to only update some of the fields in the zoo member channel.

But when i submit that form, it updates the fields in the tag, but wipes out the info of all other fields!

Any way round this? I don't really want to include all other custom fields as hidden fields!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a skeleton version of your form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is a bug that only effects native EE relationship fields. Marvellous..

Comment: It might help others if you provided the versions of ZV and EE that you're using, and if there is a reference to where you found out it's a bug or what release is expected to fix it.