# Campaigner + Zoo Visitor, updating categories causes unsubscription

Tags: zoo-visitor, campaignmonitor

We have a site using Campaigner and Zoo Visitor to sign people up to a mailing list at Campaign Monitor when they register an account on the site.

This works OK but we are seeing some odd behaviour and I'm trying to work out if it's correct, a bug or what we can do to avoid it.

The problem comes when we update categories on the entries created by Zoo Visitor. It seems that changing any categories causes Campaigner to unsubscribe the user from the mailing list at Campaign Monitor.

I have no idea why this might be happening. Can anyone shed any light on this?

I'm wondering if it could be related to this issue [Zoo Visitor update_form to update only some entries wipes out all other data](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13912/zoo-visitor-update-form-to-update-only-some-entries-wipes-out-all-other-data)

Comment: Sounds like a clear bug. Have you contacted the developers?

Comment: Not yet. I have been testing on a development site and can't replicate the issue so I think I need to delve in a bit further to work out what triggers it.